# FabricJS: Sub Classing fabric.Line and toObject error

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have successfully subclassed Groups in the past with fabricjs, however I am having all sorts of issues with the `toObject()` method when trying to subclass Line objects.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
fabric.ConnectorLine = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {
    initialize: function (points, options) {
        options || (options = {});
        this.callSuper('initialize', points, options);
        options &&
            this.set('type', 'connector') &&
            this.set('end1', options.end1) &&
            this.set('arrow', options.arrow)
    },
    toObject: function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
            type: this.type,
            end1: this.end1,
            arrow: this.arrow
        });
    }
});

fabric.ConnectorLine.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
    var _enlivenedObjects;
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects(object.objects, function (enlivenedObjects) {
        delete object.objects;
        _enlivenedObjects = enlivenedObjects;
    });
    return new fabric.ConnectorLine(_enlivenedObjects, object);
};
```

When I try to serialize this object, I get the following error message:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at klass.callSuper (fabric.js:1475:30)
at klass.fabric.Line.fabric.util.createClass.toObject (fabric.js:13632:26)
```

Is there something special you need to do with the `toObject` method with Lines (Rect and Triangle seems to have the same issue also)?

Just about done my head in, so any help is most appreciated.

**UPDATE 1: jsfiddle added**

Here is the jsfiddle of a basic example. You can see at line 124, 125 I add a reference to the line that an end and arrow is attached to:

```
arrow.line = line;
end.line = line;
```

It is this reference that throws the errors when you try to serialize (check the console):

http://jsfiddle.net/iamadamjowett/zL5k0zx3/29/

Comment: +1 try to add a JSFiddle of example

Comment: @wintermute I have just added it, see the edit above

Comment: your serialization code fall in infinite recursion, this statement **end.line = line;** is the responsible, end.line point to line, but line.end point to end

Comment: Ah I see @wintermute what you mean, so how to keep a reference of what line an end belongs to (and then what ends a line has), or should that reference be held elsewhere? It does give me a new line of thinking though, thanks. Remember to add your answer as an answer rather than a comment so I can up vote it if it is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have already wrote in the above comment, your serialization fail because the line component, the end component and the arrow component have circular reference to each other, so when you serialize the line, serialize the end which serialize the line, which serialize the end and so on, until you fall in a stack-overflow exception.

I would like suggest you to change your design, use instead a group and add your line, end and arrow to group; extend the group should be the best option, you can imagine it as a single component with 3 subcomponent not strictly referenced.

I tried an ugly and dirty solution, but there is not what I was looking for:

```
fabric.ConnectorEnd = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {

      initialize: function (options) {
        options || (options = {});
        this.callSuper('initialize', options);
        recursionCount = 0;
        options &&
            this.set('type', 'connector-end') &&
            this.set('line', options.line) &&
            this.set('attachedTo', options.attachedTo) &&
            this.set('attachedPos', options.attachedPos)
      },
      toObject: function () {
        if (recursionCount > 100) return; // added a recursion limit
        recursionCount++;
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
          type: this.type,
          line: this.line,
          attachedTo: this.attachedTo,
          attachedPos: this.attachedPos
        });
      }
    });
```

Will not work...

```
fabric.ConnectorEnd = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {

            initialize: function (options) {
                options || (options = {});
                this.callSuper('initialize', options);

                options &&
                    this.set('type', 'connector-end') &&
                    this.set('line', options.line) &&
                    this.set('attachedTo', options.attachedTo) &&
                    this.set('attachedPos', options.attachedPos) &&
                    this.set('recursions', 0)
            },
            toObject: function () {
                if (this.line.recursions > 0 && this.recursions > 1) { return; }
                return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
                    recursions: this.recursions++,
                    type: this.type,
                    line: this.line,
                    attachedTo: this.attachedTo,
                    attachedPos: this.attachedPos
                });
            }
        });
```

Will not work... terrible and useless... how can I suggest you to use this type of shitty code? What can I do? Right, the unique solution I have found to manage circular reference in JSON is [**Cycle.js of Douglas Crockford**](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js), but to use it you should modify the `.toJSON()` method of FabricJS.

My opinion is to use a property ID and a FindById Method, or use a string property where you will stringify the reference, but try, if you can, to avoid circular reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, in this case a group doesn't work due to the need to "grab" each end of the line to change it's rotation etc. (the demo doesn't show that, my bad). In saying that, your answer pointed me in the right direction, and when I solve the issue, I will be sure to update with the solution.